# POS Tagging with jvntextpro

Tags: java, pos-tagger

Has someone got experience with [Jvntextpro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvntextpro/develop) ? I want to use it to POS Tag Data in Vietnamese but don't know how to handle with this tool. What files should be modified and which format should the input file have?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [NLP Standford Postagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/) instead and its one of the best POS tagging tool.

Just download the zip file and extract it.

In  that you have a folder as models

In that models you have two files

one is props file and another one is tagger file. this code to read input file and use the tagger to tag the words. Search for the Vietnamese tagger file.

```
             {

              f = new FileReader(fileName);
              String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
              MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("yourtaggerfile.tagger");
              String tagged = tagger.tagString(content);

             }
```

Comment: Stanford has never released models for working with Vietnamese.